# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' In node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" from this part of my code

```
export const checkAdmin = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.userId });
  if (user.role !== "admin") {
    res.send({
      authorised: true
    })
  } else {
    res.send({
      authorised: false
    })
  }
};
```

I searched around and someone said i have to use babel so I did command

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

and made a file called .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  }
```

tried running again but still gives the same error

```
const User = require("../models/User.js");

export const checkAdmin = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.userId });
  if (user.role !== "admin") {
    res.send({
      authorised: true
    })
  } else {
    res.send({
      authorised: false
    })
  }
};

export const getStats = async (req, res) => {
```

Comment: `export/import` is only supported in modules, so maybe you are running into this? Since the code you show is Express code, adding babel won't do anything (no point in transpiling your up-to-date server's code for "older browsers").

Comment: I can’t think of anything that should trigger an error for `export` as the first thing in a file. Likely your problem is caused by you putting `export` immediately after whatever proceeds it but which you haven’t shown us.

Comment: (While Babel probably isn’t the solution to your problem: Installing Babel, creating a Babel config file, and then **not running Babel** isn’t going to help).

Comment: @Quentin can you check my edited question? I have to define User at the start to use it, it's not possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to mix `require` (used in CommonJS modules) with `export` (used in ECMAScript modules). Pick a module system and stick to it.